# log4j with timestamp per log entry

Tags: java, python, log4j, jython

this is my log output

```
INFO main digestemails - process inbox
INFO main digestemails - checking for emails in c:\development\DCMail\email\KN-Source
INFO main digestemails - digesting 003d01c95a7b_3446880_0202fea9@xxxx.com.eml
INFO main digestemails - extracting attachments
INFO main digestemails - no attachments or no attachments supported
INFO main digestemails - updating database
INFO main digestemails - email -> COMPLETED folder
INFO main digestemails -
```

I would like a time stamp per log message ie

```
INFO 2008-12-25 13:14:00 digestemails - email -> COMPLETED folder
```

here is my log4j config file

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=c:\\development\\DCMail\\logs\\digestlogfolder\\digest-logfile.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use `%d` in your PatternLayout.

Also `%d` can take a format pattern as in `%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}` you can pick and choose the elements that you want.  When the format pattern is omitted the date will be in ISO8601 format.

Comment: Just to add to this, I wanted to make my class signature smaller, so I used `%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n`. the **{1}** prints only c, instead of a.b.c of the class signature.

Answer (score 18):

A extract from my properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, logfile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p (%t) [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=C:/log/client.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find more conversion characters usage in log4j javadoc.For example, at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html.